# App works in debugging mode, failes when ran directly

Tags: java, selenium, debugging

I have a testing application written in java-selenium. This app tests e-shop whether it is possible to buy products and many other functionalities.

Few days ago, I added a new functionality that tests whether the payment was successful. In case the order was not successful, "#errorBox" is added into the URL, therefore I am checking whether the URL consists of this sequence:

```
public void paymentCheck() {
    String URL = driver.getCurrentUrl();
    if (URL.contains("#errorBox")) {
        data.put("paymentFailed", "true");
    } else {
        data.put("paymentFailed", "false");
    }
}
```

If there is "#errorBox", paymentFailed = true is added to the dataset. Then I check its presence:

```
.paymentCheck();

    if (dataRow.get("paymentFailed").equals("true")) {
        resultLine.addTestResultLineItem(
                new TestResultLineItemMessage("ERROR: Payment declined, transaction was not accepted.").setResult(Result.FAIL)
        );
        driver.quit();
    }
```

And the problem is: When debugging, the check works just fine. When the app is ran directly, test fails because the application skips setting result as FAILED and does not kill the driver either.

Any ideas what is wrong here?

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When in debug model,  some latency insert between each step, when run directly, we should add some sleep/wait before `driver.getCurrentUrl()` too.

From my experience, generally payment take little long time.

Answer (score 0):

The script is working fine in debug mode and is failing in normal run. This is a clear indication of latency. Include Thread.sleep(seconds) in your code. Though it is not recommended to use thread.sleep(), it is a better option, since we don't know the nature of the application. Else you can try Implicit wait or explicit wait condition in your code.